# How to run e2e tests headless with command line in cypress

Tags: automation, cypress, end-to-end

I am using cypress testing server.
When I am running my tests with cypress window, its working right.

```
 $./node_modules/.bin/cypress open --project  tests/e2e/
```

But when I am trying to run it with command line, my tests didn't worked.
In screenshots I see, that my link doesn't loading and my page is empty and my tests result is false.
I am running with selected command

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --config pageLoadTimeout=10000,watchForFileChanges=false --project  tests/e2e/
```

How I can run my tests with command line

Answer (score 0):

First you should navigate to your project folder, for example if your cypress test is lying in below folder

`C:/Project/`

From the command prompt you should cd to the project folder, ie `cd C:/Project/`, now copy the cypress bin path as follows  `C:\Project\node_modules\.bin\` paste the path and then from there run the following command:

cypress run `C:\Project\cypress\integration\examples\test-spec.js`

note: *This is tested and run in windows 10 environment*

Comment: I am in my project folder and run tests i there, but I can't ran only write cypress, for it I run it with ./node_modules/.bin/cypress